# Good free CSS Sprite for icons

Tags: css, website-design, sprite

I am working on a small project where I need some of the basic icons: edit, favorite, delete. You know them.

Now i can download them all seperate, and put them together in a sprite, but I was wondering if there are ready to download sprites which I can use.

Now I am working on an accounting app, so it would be nice if the icons were not too childish. A little but of fancy business type icons.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tango Desktop Project is an open-source project that produces some great icons.  They even have [just such a image](http://tango.freedesktop.org/images/2/20/Tango-feet.png) as you describe.  You can find it by scrolling down on their [icon library page](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Icon_Library).

The actual icons are (per the project's homepage) released to the Public Domain, so there will be no copyright issues whatsoever in using them.

Comment: Cool. Ill grab that one.

Answer (score 2):

what about glyphicons ? you can even use bootstrap css to use them directly http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons

Comment: This is the link to [glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The [famfamfam silk icons](http://www.famfamfam.com/archive/silk-icons-thats-your-lot/) might work well for you, there are 1000 to choose from. You'll have to combine them into your own sprite though.

Comment: +1 Thank you i've used these before. They are great, but for this project i will go with a ready to go pack.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try

http://www.iconfinder.com

and you have to combine all of them foe CSS sprites.

Comment: I know that, read my question again, im not looking for this answer.